# Multiple fields in fact table referring to one dimension Qlikview

Tags: qlikview, dimensional-modeling

I am new to Qlikview.
I have a fact table Fact_Transaction with fields CheckinDate and CheckoutDate. and I have a dimensional table Dim_Time with Date_ID as PK.

```
//-------- Start Multiple Select Statements ------
LOAD "Property_SK",
    TotalNoOfDays,
    PerDayCost,
    TotalCost,
    "Guest_FName",
    "Guest_LName",
    "Host_FName",
    "Host_LName",
    CurrRecInd,
    "User_SK_Guest",
    "User_SK_Host",
    "CheckInDate_SK",
    "CheckOutDate_SK";
SQL SELECT *
FROM "Airbnb database".dbo."Fact_Transaction";

LOAD "Date_ID",
    "Calender_Date",
    "Day_of_Week",
    WeekoftheYear,
    WeekoftheMonth,
    DayoftheMonth,
    CalenderYear,
    CalenderMonth,
    CalenderQuarter,
    FiscalYear,
    FiscalQuarter,
    FiscalMonth;
SQL SELECT *
FROM "Airbnb database".dbo."Dim_Time";


//-------- End Multiple Select Statements ------
```

Now i want to link the fields CheckinDate and CheckoutDate with Dim_Time on Date_ID.
How do i implement the same in Qlikview? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Being two different dimension (and therefore two different concepts) I would recomend creating two separate dimesion tables. Something like this :

- Load the Fact table as you are doing already
- Load the Dim_Time Table for the CheckIn Dimension, renaming the Date_ID column to CheckInDate_SK as the other columns from something like WeekoftheMonth to CheckInDate_WeekoftheMonth.
- Load (again) the Dim_Time Table for the CheckOut Dimension, renaming the Date_ID column to CheckOutDate_SK as the other columns from something like WeekoftheMonth to CheckOutDate_WeekoftheMonth.

You can rename the columns by adding the "as" keyword, for instance :

- Date_ID as CheckInDate_SK

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the IntervalMatch function: see [here](http://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/12.1/Subsystems/Client/Content/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/IntervalMatch.htm)
Its a very powerful function.

Just follow the example case in the help - it should be very similar to your case.